# Adding SQL Statement with all tables and column names into a Dictionary

Tags: c#, dictionary

I need to save a sql SELECT Statement, which includes all tables and its columns in a database. The statement works fine and i can get all the names from the tables and columns i need.

The result looks as follows: (this is just psuedo-something)

```
            table_Name  Column_name
            - CallerIP  DT
            - CallerIP  ID
            - CallerIP  IP
            - queueObject Action
            - queueObject Attempt
            - queueObject DestinationAddress
            - queueObject ID
```

I thougt, i can save it into a `Dictionary`, where the tableName is a `String`, and the Colum_Names is a `List` of `Strings`

```
private Dictionary<string, List<string>> rowAndTables = new Dictionary<string, List<string>>();
```

this is my code, which should add all the tables and rows into the Dictionary

```
        //Some code above, that doesnt matter here
        command = new SqlCommand(sqlSelect, SqlConnector.getConnection());
        command.Connection = SqlConnector.getConnection();
        reader = command.ExecuteReader();

        while (reader.Read()) {
            if (tempTableName.Equals(reader.GetString(0)) == false) {
                tempTableName = reader.GetString(0);
                tempColumn = reader.GetString(1);
                Console.WriteLine(tempTableName);
                Console.WriteLine(tempColumn);
            } else {
                tempColumn = reader.GetString(1);
                Console.WriteLine(tempColumn);
            }

        }
```

This doesnt do anything, besides printing all tables and columns.
The result looks as follows:
//CONSOLE...

```
CallerIP //Table
DT
ID
IP
queue_object //Table
Action
Attempt
DestinationAddress
ID
```

So the *printing is fine*.
Now I am struggeling with adding it into a `Dictionary`.
Can anyone help ?
Anything I did made no sense, and would just confuse anyone, I guess.

Comment: *"Anything i did made no sense"* Please show it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, if you want to fill the dictionary

```
private Dictionary<string, List<string>> rowAndTables = 
  new Dictionary<string, List<string>>();
```

you should modify your code slightly:

```
    ...

    //DONE: wrap IDisposable (command) into using in order to release resources
    using (var command = new SqlCommand(sqlSelect, SqlConnector.getConnection())) {
      // Redundant, can be dropped
      command.Connection = SqlConnector.getConnection();

      using (var reader = command.ExecuteReader()) {
        //TODO: check if the key and value are correct ones 
        string key = Convert.ToString(reader[0]);
        string value = Convert.ToString(reader[1]);

        // Do we have the key (and corresponding list) in the dictionary?
        if (rowAndTables.TryGetValue(key, out var list))  
          // yes - we should add the value to the existing list 
          list.Add(value); 
        else 
          // no - we have to create key and list with value 
          rowAndTables.Add(key, new List<string>() {value}); 
      }
    }
```

Comment: @Cid: I've edited the answer: you are quite right - if OP experiences difficulties with the dictionary, comments on `TryGetValue` should be provided.

Comment: Thank you this worked good! Is this normal c# ? i didnt see anything like that. Im just doing c# for 2 month.

Comment: @NameGuy what do you mean ? The `using() {  }` directives ?

Comment: @Cid yes and the " out var list"

Comment: `out var list` - `out` is required for `out` parameters; `var` is substitution of `List<string>` - we ask compiler to derive the actual type for us; however we can put it as `...TryGetValue(key, out List<string> list) ...`

Comment: when you are doing `command = new SqlCommand(sqlSelect, SqlConnector.getConnection());` and then `command.Connection = SqlConnector.getConnection();` You will have later to `Close();` that connection. This is called **unmanaged resources**. When you are doing `using (var command = new SqlCommand(sqlSelect, SqlConnector.getConnection())) { }` it will open the connection and close it when you leave the `{  }` scope. For more details, see [IDisposable](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.idisposable?view=netframework-4.8) documentation